# asp.net button.onclientclick and button.text empty in jquery dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a control that should prompt the user to choose either the session's customerId or the page's old ViewState customerId. If the value in the viewstate does not match the value in session a jQuery modal dialog will appear. The dialog has two buttons, one should display the ViewState value and the other should display the session value. The button with the ViewState value also has a OnClientClick property. I have tested this code with a simple test page that includes only a single button and my control. The simple test page worked. When I added this control to a an existing page I could get the dialog to show but button.text (assigned in the code behind) was empty and the function for OnClientClick would not fire.

ascx

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowCustomerChangedModalDialog() {
        var dlg = $("#CustomerChangedModal").dialog({
            title: 'Select Customer ID',
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });
        dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    };

    function changeCustomer(customerId, baseUrl) {
        $.ajax({ url: "/General/Accounts/change.account?id=" + customerId + "&admin=false", async: false });
        $("#CustomerChangedModal").dialog('close');
        return false;
    }

</script>

<div id="CustomerChangedModal" style="width: 440px; height: 250px; overflow: auto; display: none;">
    The session information has changed.
    Which account ID do you wish to use?
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnNewCustId" runat="server" OnClick="btnNewCustId_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnOldCustId" runat="server" />
</div>
```

code behind

```
public partial class CustomerChanged : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        this.Page.PreLoad += Page_PreLoad;
    }

    void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState.Add("CustID", Globals.CurrentCust.CustId);
        }
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Page.Validate();
            ValidateCustomerId();
        }
    }

    protected void ValidateCustomerId()
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["CustID"]) != Globals.CurrentCust.CustId)
        {
            //button properties assignments
            btnOldCustId.Text += "Old AccountId\n" + ViewState["CustID"].ToString();
            btnNewCustId.Text += "New AccountId\n" + Globals.CurrentCust.CustId.ToString();
            btnOldCustId.OnClientClick = string.Format("return changeCustomer({0},'{1}');", ViewState["CustID"].ToString(), Globals.GeneralSiteUrl);

            CustomValidator err = new CustomValidator();
            err.IsValid = false;
            err.ErrorMessage = "The customer has changed.";
            Page.Validators.Add(err);
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!Page.IsValid)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "CustomerChangedModalDialog", "ShowCustomerChangedModalDialog();", true);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnNewCustId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess the value in your `if` statement in `ValidateCustomerId()` wasn't `true`. What is the `else` case?

Comment: `else` carry on as usual. There would be no dialog shown and any task that was happening before would continue uninterrupted.

Comment: Right... but then you are never setting the button text and your event isn't assigned. Isn't that your problem? You only have text/event on `Postback` when your `if` statement is `true`. Just checking to make sure all your criteria is being met.

Comment: I appreciate any interest in helping me with this problem. It is always a good idea to step back and examine the steps in the code. Thank you for reminding me of that. This control is intended to check for mismatched cutomerIDs, inform the user, and prompt the user to take action to resolve the situation. As far as I can tell the code that I have does that. It worked on a simple test page that I created but doesn't work on a more complex page. I think the page that I have the control on is interfering in some way. I don't know how to identify the cause if that is the case.

Comment: Time to put in breakpoints and and hit F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped trying to use server side code and switched to javascript to assign the button text and to reloading the page with the new customerId. This doesn't answer my question as to why the server side properties where not behaving as I expected but it gets the job done for now.

```
var div = $("#CustomerChangedModal");
var oldButton = $("[id$=btnOldCustId]", div);
var newButton = $("[id$=btnNewCustId]", div);
newButton.val("New AccountId " + newId);
oldButton.val("Old AccountId " + oldId);
newButton.on("click", function (event) { changeCustomerNew(newId) });
oldButton.on("click", function (event) { changeCustomerOld(oldId) });
```